# How to find if an array has at least 10 unique integers in $O(\log n)$?

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms

I am given a sorted array of integers. I want to find out if the array has at least 10 unique integers. I know this can easily be done with an algorithm that runs in $O(n)$ simply by going through each element and making comparisons, but how can this be done in $O(\log n)$ ?

Comment: Hint: what do you know how to do with a sorted array in $O(\log n)$?

Comment: I have tried splitting it in two, but for it to be $O(\log n)$ I need to recurs on only one half. However I am not sure how a smaller array helps me.

Comment: What I mean is, what other algorithms (on a sorted array) do you already know that have $O(\log n)$ behavior? Can one of them help you with this problem?

Comment: I know of binary search, but I don't think that helps me.

Comment: Why not? Bigger hint: what happens when you binary search for an element that isn't there?

Answer (score 0):

It's sorted, so we have the smallest element to be the first element of the array. Given an element $k$, can you find the last occurrence of $k$ in the array (hint: see the comments)? Since it's the last occurrence of $k$ in the array, we know that the next element after that is different than $k$. If you can do that, then just repeat this 10 times.